# How do I write to an HTML file using expressjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Ok, this sounds crazy, but let me explain. I want a user to be able to push a button, and then the html file is edited in such a way that it a NEW p element is created, and stays there PERMENENTLY (eg on reload and for EVERYONE to see). Any way on how I could do that.

Again I am using node.js/express, and html/js/css.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon exactly what you're doing.

Conceptually, you would probably use some sort of template system for generating your HTML files (like Jade, Dust, EJS, Handlebars, Nunjucks, PUG, etc..) and then you store some state in a database and use a query from the database as input to the template whenever you render a particular page.

So, when you add an item to the database, it will show up in all future renders of the page.

So, your button would trigger a form post to your server which would add an item to the database and the response from the form post would be a rendering of the page after adding the item to the database.  All future renders of the page from all users would also show those same items in the rendered page.